# Появляющийся div

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы `div` с контентом появлялся и исчезал при нажатии на ссылку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.link').click(function(){
$('div').toggle();

});​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/WbvfT/3/

Answer (score 1):

Если ты не знаком с JS то напиши я тебе функцию готовую дам

Если знаком то

```
display //CSS
.style.display //JS
```

Answer (score 0):

[Плавное появление или изменение прозрачности](http://easywebscripts.net/javascript/opacity.php), вешать на `onClick` у ссылки

или на `jquery`

```
#('#mylink').click(function(){$("#mydiv").fadeToggle("slow");})
```